# Are Japanese culture questions derived from animes on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

For example,

> In anime XYZ, W person behaved this way.
>
> Why did he do so, is this common in Japan?

Is this kind of question on-topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, questions in regards to the Japanese [culture](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) are considered on topic.
As the tag excerpt reads:

> Questions about anime and manga in the broader context of Japanese culture. Includes both **questions about cultural origins for anime/manga references** and questions about the cultural impact of a particular series.

In certain cases, it might also relate to the [tropes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tropes) as this is all about re-occurring events

> Tropes: A recurring element across anime, manga or works in other media. Tropes cover clichés, genre conventions and other recurring plot points, character types, narration styles, …

If you have a such a question, you can take some inspiration from questions [Tagged as culture+tropes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture+tropes).